# Analytics ignoring virtual page sent ga

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am setting a virtual page tracking ga js in order to capture a form submission, and track the conversion.

I have been following instructions on how to do it:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

I've written the snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('set', 'page', '/contacto-pergola.html');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Right before the ADWORDS conversion snippet.

I have registered a new goal containing:
Goal Setup: custom
Goal Type: Destination
equals to: /contacto-pergola

However after I load the destination page which should trigger the virtual page sent:
http://sungates.es/pergola-bioclimatica/distributeur.html#ancreErreur

Analytics doesn't track anything.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any chance you are using a filtered view for the Real Time report?

Comment: I am in:
CONVERSIONS->OVERVIEW->GOALS, and goal info is 0, while I've been testing form submissions. Is there a way to debug and see the info sent to analytics? I am using tag assistant, but i guess it's not enough

Comment: This (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) is a good Chrome extension you can use to see exactly what data is sent to GA.